# Can't get Eloquent's hasManyThrough to work for a basic example

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Here are my relationships:

`User`

- id

`Collection`

- id

`UserCollection`

- user_id
- collection_id

How can I get something like `$user->collections` to return all `Collection` objects that belongs to the user? A `UserCollection` simply links a `User` to a `Collection`. This allows a user to have multiple collections, but also allows a collection to belong to multiple users.

What I'm currently trying is to specify that `UserCollection` belongs to a `User` on `user_id`, and belongs to a `Collection` on `collection_id`.

```
// UserCollection

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}

public function collection()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Collection::class, 'collection_id');
}
```

Then specifying that a `User` has many `Collections` through `UserCollection`.

```
// User

public function collections()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Collection::class, UserCollection::class);
}
```

I've also tried explicitly setting the column names of the `hasManyThrough` relationship, but the join tries to use an `id` column on the `UserCollection` model, which does not exist as there is no primary key:

```
public function collections()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Collection::class, UserCollection::class, 'user_id', 'collection_id');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overcomplicating things here. You don't need `hasManyThrough`. What you need is `belongsToMany()` for a many-to-many relationship.

First, get rid of your `UserCollection` model. You don't need it.

Then change your relations to this:

```
public function collections(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Collection', 'user_collections');
}

public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'user_collections');
}
```

For more information take a look at the [official docs on relations](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#relationships)

Comment: Would I need to create the join table or is it implied?

Comment: Yes you need a join table. But since you already have (or had) a `UserCollection` model I assume you have a corresponding table too...

Comment: Yes I do have that table. So what happens when a new link is to be made between a user and a collection? Previously I was creating a new `UserCollection`. The way I see it I do need that model, but I don't need `hasManyThrough`.

Comment: Take a look at the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#relationships) first and ask again if you still need help.

Comment: @paranoid-android No, that model doesn't make sense as it per se holds no information. The relations are defined on either model, and that is just enough. Define a hasMany and a belongsToMany relationship in both models.